# Solutions for counting trapped water on islands

Tags: java, programming-challenge

There are some exercises about islands and water. I have seen other solutions in Java, but they are developed in procedural style in one-two methods. I tried to develop an object-oriented solution with code reuse. I have never got code reviews before, so I would happy to see **any** suggestions to improve my code.

---

### Exercise 1.

> There is a beach with a ground configuration like
>
> ```
> [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 2, 3, 1 ]
> ```
>
> A wave come from a sea to the left of the beach. 
>   Its height is 5, for example.
>   Then the wave come back to the sea.
>   In the beach's hollows we find trapped water.
>   If the wave is higher than beach it covers the full beach 
>   and goes away to both directions.
>
> Task: write a program for counting all trapped water 
>   on the whole beach.

---

### Exercise 2.

> There is an island with a ground configuration like
>
> ```
>  [
>   [ 5, 3, 4, 5 ],
>   [ 6, 2, 1, 4 ],
>   [ 3, 1, 1, 4 ],
>   [ 8, 5, 4, 3 ]
>  ]
> ```
>
> A rain was many days.
>   It filled by water every hollow in the island.
>   Water can go away only to 4 directions: 
>   north, south, west, east.
>
> Task: write a program for counting 
>    all trapped water in whole island.
>   For example, the answer for a given configuration is 7.

---

At first, I developed the common class for a single column of land with water on it:

```
package trappedwater;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class LithosphereSection {

    /* Height is above mean sea level in each case */
    public final int groundHeight;
    private int waterHeight;

    public LithosphereSection(int _groundHeight) {
        this.groundHeight = _groundHeight;
        this.waterHeight = 0;
    }

    public void setWaterHeight(int _waterHeight) {
        this.waterHeight = _waterHeight;
    }

    public void extraWaterPourOff(LithosphereSection... neighborSections) {
        if (hasPrecipiceForWater(neighborSections)) {
            this.waterHeight = 0;
        } else {
            for (LithosphereSection neighbor : neighborSections) {
                int support = Integer.max(neighbor.waterHeight, neighbor.groundHeight);
                this.waterHeight = Integer.min(this.waterHeight, support);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPrecipiceForWater(LithosphereSection... neighborSections) {
        return neighborSections == null
                || neighborSections.length == 0
                || Arrays.asList(neighborSections).contains(null);
    }

    public int getTrappedWater() {
        int trappedWater = this.waterHeight - this.groundHeight;
        return (trappedWater > 0) ? trappedWater : 0;
    }
}
```

---

Then I solved the first exercise.

```
package trappedwater;

public class Beach {

    private final LithosphereSection[] litSections;
    private final int m; // alias to litSections.length

    public Beach(int[] _groundScheme) {
        this.m = _groundScheme.length;
        this.litSections = new LithosphereSection[this.m];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.m; i++) {
            this.litSections[i] = new LithosphereSection(_groundScheme[i]);
        }
    }

    public void takeWaveFromLeft(int _waveHeight) {
        boolean waveStillMoves = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.m; i++) {
            if (waveStillMoves) {
                if (_waveHeight > this.litSections[i].groundHeight) {
                    this.litSections[i].setWaterHeight(_waveHeight);
                } else {
                    waveStillMoves = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void extraWaterPourOff() {
        // Pour water on boarders
        this.litSections[0].extraWaterPourOff();
        this.litSections[this.m - 1].extraWaterPourOff();

        // Pour water to the left
        for (int i = 1; i < this.m - 1; i++) {
            this.litSections[i].extraWaterPourOff(this.litSections[i - 1]);
        }

        // Pour water to the right
        for (int i = this.m - 2; i > 0; i--) {
            this.litSections[i].extraWaterPourOff(this.litSections[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    public int getTrappedWater() {
        int sumWater = 0;
        for (LithosphereSection litSection : this.litSections) {
            sumWater += litSection.getTrappedWater();
        }
        return sumWater;
    }

    public void dry() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.m; i++) {
            this.litSections[i].setWaterHeight(0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

And the second one

```
package trappedwater;

public class Island {

    private final LithosphereSection[][] litSections;
    private final int n; // rows
    private final int m; // columns
    private int highestGround;

    public Island(int[][] _groundScheme) {
        this.n = _groundScheme.length;
        this.m = _groundScheme[0].length;

        this.litSections = new LithosphereSection[this.n][this.m];
        this.highestGround = _groundScheme[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.m; j++) {
                this.litSections[i][j] = new LithosphereSection(_groundScheme[i][j]);
                this.highestGround = Integer.max(this.highestGround, _groundScheme[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void overfillByWater() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.m; j++) {
                this.litSections[i][j].setWaterHeight(this.highestGround);
            }
        }
    }

    public void extraWaterPourOff() {
        pourOffBoarders();
        boolean countOfPuddlesChanges = true;
        while (countOfPuddlesChanges) {
            int countOfPuddlesBefore = getTrappedWater();
            pourOffToNorthLeft();
            pourOffToSouthRight();
            countOfPuddlesChanges = (getTrappedWater() != countOfPuddlesBefore);
        }
    }

    private void pourOffBoarders() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.m; j++) {
                boolean isBorder = (i == 0) || (i == this.n - 1) || (j == 0) || (j == this.m - 1);
                if (isBorder) {
                    this.litSections[i][j].extraWaterPourOff();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void pourOffToNorthLeft() {
        for (int i = 1; i < this.n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < this.m - 1; j++) {
               this.litSections[i][j].extraWaterPourOff(
                        this.litSections[i][j - 1],
                        this.litSections[i - 1][j]
               );
            }
        }
    }

    private void pourOffToSouthRight() {
        for (int i = this.n - 2; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = this.m - 2; j > 0; j--) {
                this.litSections[i][j].extraWaterPourOff(
                        this.litSections[i][j + 1],
                        this.litSections[i + 1][j]
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public int getTrappedWater() {
        int sumWater = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.m; j++) {
                sumWater += this.litSections[i][j].getTrappedWater();
            }
        }
        return sumWater;
    }
}
```

---

Finally I made 3 classes with JUnit5 tests:

```
package trappedwater;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class LithosphereSectionTest {

    static LithosphereSection testLitSection;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        testLitSection = new LithosphereSection(5);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        testLitSection.setWaterHeight(10);
    }

    @Test
    void test01() {
        assertEquals(5, testLitSection.getTrappedWater());
    }

    @Test
    void test02() {
        LithosphereSection litSection2 = new LithosphereSection(7);
        LithosphereSection litSection3 = new LithosphereSection(8);
        LithosphereSection litSection4 = new LithosphereSection(6);
        litSection4.setWaterHeight(7);

        testLitSection.extraWaterPourOff(litSection2, litSection3, litSection4);
        assertEquals(2, testLitSection.getTrappedWater());
    }

    @Test
    void test03() {
        testLitSection.extraWaterPourOff();
        assertEquals(0, testLitSection.getTrappedWater());
    }

    @Test
    void test04() {
        LithosphereSection[] sections = null;
        testLitSection.extraWaterPourOff(sections);
        assertEquals(0, testLitSection.getTrappedWater());
    }

    @Test
    void test05() {
        LithosphereSection litSection2 = null;
        testLitSection.extraWaterPourOff(litSection2);
        assertEquals(0, testLitSection.getTrappedWater());
    }
}
```

---

```
package trappedwater;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class BeachTest {

    static Beach beach;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        int[] groundScheme = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 2, 3, 1 };
        beach = new Beach(groundScheme);
    }

    private int run(int waveHeight) {
        beach.dry();
        beach.takeWaveFromLeft(waveHeight);
        beach.extraWaterPourOff();
        return beach.getTrappedWater();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals(0, run(1));
        assertEquals(0, run(2));
        assertEquals(0, run(3));
        assertEquals(1, run(4));
        assertEquals(1, run(5));
        assertEquals(6, run(6));
        assertEquals(6, run(7));
        assertEquals(8, run(8));
        assertEquals(8, run(9));
    }
}
```

---

```
package trappedwater;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class IslandTest {

    private int run(int[][] _groundScheme) {
        Island island = new Island(_groundScheme);
        island.overfillByWater();
        island.extraWaterPourOff();
        return island.getTrappedWater();
    }

    @Test
    void test01() {
        int[][] groundScheme = new int[][] {
            { 5, 3, 4, 5 },
            { 6, 2, 1, 4 },
            { 3, 1, 1, 4 },
            { 8, 5, 4, 3 }
        };
        assertEquals(7, run(groundScheme));
    }

    @Test
    void test02() {
        int[][] groundScheme = new int[][] {
            { 8, 6, 8, 8 },
            { 8, 2, 2, 4 },
            { 8, 2, 2, 8 },
            { 8, 8, 8, 8 }
        };
        assertEquals(8, run(groundScheme));
    }
}
```

## Edited

These are 2 different challenges. Someone can offer to make 2 different questions. But I think I found a universal solution for family of problems. The challenges seems to be different, but solutions are identical for me. For example, here is a new challenge.

---

> We have an island:
>
> ```
> [
>  [ 3, 3, 4, 5, 2 ],
>  [ 6, 2, 1, 4, 4 ],
>  [ 3, 1, 7, 4, 6 ],
>  [ 4, 5, 4, 3, 2 ],
>  [ 2, 3, 5, 2, 3 ]
> ]
> ```
>
> Winter was cold. The island is covered by snow layers:
>
> ```
> [
>  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
>  [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 0 ],
>  [ 0, 1, 4, 0, 0 ],
>  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
>  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
> ]
> ```
>
> Summer come. Will melt water reach the ocean?

---

I would not change class LithosphereSection to solve this new challenge.

Or, we have a hexagonically divided map of island. Each lithosphere section can have up to 6 neighbors in this challenge. I would not change class LithosphereSection. LithosphereSection can have any amount of neighbors: 2 for 2D challenge, 4 for 3D quadratic challenge, 6 for 3D hexagonic challenge, 8 for 3D quadratic challenge with additional diagonal directions for water pouring. So, I think class LithosphereSection solves a family of similar problems, I wanted to show this.

Comment: Tests help reviewers tremendously when reviewing your code. If you have them you should definitely provide them.

Comment: These are 2 different challenges. Perhaps it would have been better to have asked 2 separate questions.

Comment: @dfhwze, I've answered to you in footer of the question. It's just my own opinion, you may be right.